# Input type="xxx" only for keyboard, without validation?

Tags: html, user-experience

Is it possible to choose input type only for custom keyboard but prevent any browser validations so that entered value could be processed by the application?

I.e.

```
<input type="number">
```

With value `12345-123`

On mobile device user would be presented with keyboard which allows to enter numbers as well as `-`. As soon as such value is entered browser returns empty string thus not allowing for me to choose and do validation on my side.

```
$0.value
```

with a return of:

```
""
```

I would like to use specific keyboards for some input types but I'm not sure if it's possible, if so - how?

Comment: `<input type="number">` will open the number keyboard. What's the problem? What's exactly the question?

Comment: I know that it does, but the problem is when I enter something like `12345-123` into the field, I can not access that value, because browser does some parsing and actually returns empty string, instead of a falsy value... So the question is - is it possible to use type number, enter invalid value and read that value with javascript

Comment: The only way I imagine right now is to have 2 inputs (one type number, one type text). The text field will show the user's input, and the number field will be 1x1 px (width and height) that's emulate the hidden. When you type on the number field you can copy character by character to the text field (that's the user can see), and you will validate text input, but not number input. Something like a trick and very hard to achieve to a very simple task.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe try with $.val() not value. you can find the documentation here:

http://api.jquery.com/val/

http://codepen.io/TunderScripts/pen/jVvzNj?editors=1111

Html:

```
<input type="number" />
```

JS using JQuery:

```
var input = $('input[type=number]');

input.on('clic change', function(){
  console.log($(this).val());
})
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Your `console.log()` produces the same result than the OP said. You can test your own codepen before answer.

Comment: Does it return null? did you even test it?

Comment: Not null, the result is empty: `""`, the same as OP said in his question.

Comment: The OP said that when the input contains 12345-678 it returns "" , go input some numbers into the input or just change it from arrows and see the console.

Comment: He needs to write numbers and the hypen symbol. It returns empty with this, so OP needs a solution for this. Your code does exactly the same than the OP's code

Comment: if you place any other other character than numbers there ofc you get empty since it's not valid. You cannot assign a value of "123-123" to a number input, it must be a text or something else. "123-123" is not a number, but if you want to have the visual aspect of that and still get a number maybe look into data masks and stop criticize people instead of coming with and idea. tnx for downvote

Comment: It's not my downvote. I'm not criticing you. This is not an answer that can solve the problem of OP. If you see my comments I write an idea that could work. Your answer doesn't works and doesn't answer the question itself. That's because this is not a valid answer, and you don't have upvotes nor accepted answer. Don't think this is a bad discussion, think that all of us are here to help anothers and ourselves.